# White Stains on stainless steel

Tags: cleaning, cookware

So these are stains that I tried to get off with everything this board has adviced. Still no end in sight.  I tried baking soda, citric acid, white vinegar, bar keeper's friend etc.

Does anyone know what these are? First time I'm getting these in 5 years of cooking, hard as hell to get off. I even tried to scratch it off but it doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: I also have stains like this on my stainless pans.

Comment: Did they slowly build up over time, or was that something in particular that caused it?

Comment: I live with two other people in this house and I know my pan was moved while I was asleep - could it be a chemical reaction of some sort? I had it sit out overnight with some Bar Keeper's Friend because I had cooked sausage in it.

Comment: @JackCheff Pretty sure Bar Keeper's Friend says on the label to rinse thoroughly within a minute (or maybe a few) - leaving it overnight might not be a good idea.

Comment: @Jefromi whoops. Funny how it hasn't ever happened until now? Is there a way to get rid of it? Or can I still cook with the pan without fearing to get poisoned?

Comment: @JackCheff I don't think the issue is getting poisoned, just that the active ingredient is oxalic acid and leaving it long term could maybe start to corrode metal a bit.

Comment: @JackCheff I don't know what the spots are, but if they refuse to get removed by your chemical and physical attacks, it is highly unlikely that they will come off in the food. So, the chance that they will poison you goes towards zero. They seem to be a cosmetic problem only.

Comment: @talon8 I tried what was suggested in that thread. Nothing helped. You guys raised good points, I doubt it will leech into the food if it didn't get off at 300F+ anyway. I guess I'll just use the pan until it dies and corrosion happens.

Comment: However, unfortunately just because there aren't any valid answers, that doesn't make this question any less of a duplicate...

Answer (score 3):

These are probably mineral deposits.  Boiling water or washing with hard(er) water can leave them.

You can scrub with a plastic pad, use vinegar, etc.  I have found that denture cleaner works well for this.  Drop one or two tablets in a pan full of cold water, let it sit for 20 mintues, and then rinse it well.  A sponge or plastic abrasive pad should remove any remanents easily.

The film will probably reappear in a few months, so regular treatment is recommended.  As for the denture cleaner, a generic brand with a hundred or so tablets will cost you a couple bucks.  Also good for cleaning stains off porcelain.

That said, it shouldn't affect the flavor or healthfulness of your food.

Comment: Denture cleaner is a novel idea. I'd love to hear if that works for the OP. +1

Comment: More uses for denture cleaner (google is your friend) [link](http://www.rd.com/home/extraordinary-uses-for-denture-tablets/)